# Restrict the audience of a website to my facebook friends only

Tags: php, facebook, web

I want to know how can i restrict the audience of a website to my facebook friends only.
i,e to view my website he or she has to

1. My friend on facebook
2. He/She must log in to the facebook before opening my website.
3. After log in He/She can view my website in other tab.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example should be able to do what you want:

http://snippetrepo.com/snippets/login-with-facebook

Just write some additional php that only allows them to view the site when they are logged in.

Comment: can these restrict only to my fb friends

Comment: I'm sure you can do some additional wrangling with the facebook API to check for your friends. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends